# Constructing a function with constant line integral in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: integration, analysis, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

Suppose, $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a bounded convex set. If, there is an integrable function $f:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $$\int_{\Omega \cap \ell} f = 1$$ for every line $\ell \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ with $\mathcal{H}^1(\ell \cap \Omega) > 0$. Then, can we claim $\Omega$ is a ball and $f$ is a radial function?

My **main question** is: How'd we go about constructing such a function if there exists one?

Any help/hint is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Is $\mathcal{H}^1(\ell \cap \Omega)$ just the length of $\ell\cap\Omega$? If so, I find it hard to believe that such a function could exist (unless by 'line' you mean 'line through the origin'; but then your claim would be false).

Comment: @TonyK $\mathcal{H}^1$ is the length. I do mean every line, not just line through one point (indeed then $\Omega$ need not be ball). It's quite counter intuitive to me too .. and have my own doubts.

Comment: Does this fact hold for a ball, btw? If we send some lines that cut the ball far away from its center, the length of the crossing becomes smaller and smaller, and since we consider any line, this function blows up to infinity on the boundary of the ball. I hence doubt that this won't cause some other line (e.g. a diameter) not to have too of a high integral value.

Comment: Just as an example, for the unit disk you can take $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-|x|^2}}$.

Comment: @Del Thank you very much!! (+1) Add it as an answer and I'd be happy to accept :D

Comment: @r9m I'll think a bit about the general convex case, and if nothing comes up I'll just write the above example with some explanation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ you can consider the function
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-|x|^2}}.$$
Then, if you take a line at distance $h$ from the origin, using the arclength parameter $t$ on the segment the integral becomes
$$\int_{-\sqrt{1-h^2}}^{\sqrt{1-h^2}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(h^2+t^2)}}dt=
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-h^2}}\int_{-\sqrt{1-h^2}}^{\sqrt{1-h^2}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{t^2}{1-h^2}}}dt=\int_{-1}^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}dy=\pi$$
by the change of variables $y=\frac{t}{\sqrt{1-h^2}}$.

**How to come up with the function?** Well, first of all we consider for simplicity a radial function $f(x)=g(|x|)$. Now in order for $f$ to have the same integral on all segments, a sufficient condition is that on each interval $f$ looks the same: if a segment is shorter than another, the function gets multiplied by the right factor to preserve the integral.

Following this idea, consider a segment at distance $h$ from the origin. Then the segment's length is $2\sqrt{1-h^2}$, and therefore the value $g(h)$ (middle point of the segment) must be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-h^2}}$ times higher than $g(0)$ (middle point of the segment through the origin) and thus
$$g(h)=\frac{g(0)}{\sqrt{1-h^2}}.$$
Luckily this works, as shown above.

Comment: (+1) Thanks for the answer!